# How to change forecolor of VisualStudio popup/quick info tips?

Tags: visual-studio, color-scheme

I cannot seem to figure out which of the 6 jillion settings in `Fonts and Colors` affects popup tips, such as the definition of a function. I need to either darken the background and/or some of the text, being as it is currently unreadable.

[image: https://hopefulbaskets.com/images/popup.jpg]

I've tried fiddling with every setting that seems like it might possibly be it, but can't find it.

Can someone please tell me the name of the setting I need to change the color for?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for: `Editor Tooltip` option in `Show settings for:`.

**Updated after OP's comment:**
To update the `Background` color, you could choose `Environment` under `Show setting for:` and adjust `ToolTip` option from the `Display items:` option.

[image]

Comment: Well, you're in the ballpark.  That setting controls the foreground color of the description text.  But it not possible to change the background color (disabled), nor the foreground colors of the keywords.  So I still have white method names, and white parameters on a nearly white background.

Comment: please see the update. That option will let you change the background of the tooltip.